# Error DSRA9542W while accessing DB2 using JNDI in WAS 8.0

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, websphere-8

I am trying to access DB2 database using JNDI in Websphere 8.0 server and DB2 Universal drivers. Whenever the connection is established the connection is fetched successfully but when a query is fired the following messages are shows in SystemOut.log:

```
[7/25/13 8:06:19:800 CDT] 0000001d WSRdbDataSour W DSRA9542W : The JDBC Driver that is configured with the data source for the Application Server does not support the extending data source properties feature. The Application Server will not honor the extended data source properties.
[7/25/13 8:06:19:816 CDT] 0000001d InternalGener I DSRA8203I : Database product name : DB2
[7/25/13 8:06:19:831 CDT] 0000001d InternalGener I DSRA8204I : Database product version : DSN10012
[7/25/13 8:06:19:831 CDT] 0000001d InternalGener I DSRA8205I: JDBC driver name : IBM DB2 JDBC Universal Driver Architecture
[7/25/13 8:06:19:831 CDT] 0000001d InternalGener I DSRA8206I : JDBC driver version : 3.52.95
[7/25/13 8:06:19:831 CDT] 0000001d InternalDB2Un I DSRA8212I : DataStoreHelper name is: com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper@3e73d63.
[7/25/13 8:06:19:831 CDT] 0000001d WSRdbDataSour I DSRA8208I : JDBC driver type : 4
```

Along with this, the following exception is thrown:

```
  
2013-07-24 19:51:10,214 ERROR [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] util.Utility (Utility.java:141) - com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.kn: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-807, SQLSTATE=23509, SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSLN300;REMOTE, DRIVER=3.52.95 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:662) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:60) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ad.a(ad.java:127) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.c(rl.java:2424) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.d(rl.java:2401) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.a(rl.java:1902) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.a(rl.java:1880) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.g(db.java:133) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.a(db.java:38) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.a(t.java:32) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.h(sb.java:141) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.rl.Y(rl.java:1873) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.bc(sl.java:2526) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.e(sl.java:3227) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.Ob(sl.java:569) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sl.executeQuery(sl.java:543) 
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1086) 
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:707) 
        at com.buildbenefitsets.dao.PCIRuleDao.getAnswerSet(PCIRuleDao.java:52) 
        at com.buildbenefitsets.pcibsirule.PCIRuleExecution.getPCIScreenData(PCIRuleExecution.java:182) 
        at com.buildbenefitsets.pcibsirule.PCIRuleExecution.getPCIReplication(PCIRuleExecution.java:65) 
        at com.buildbenefitsets.jobs.MSIorPCIWriteJob.execute(MSIorPCIWriteJob.java:66) 
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) 
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

When i test connection from Websphere admin terminal, the connection is successful. 
I tried using normal JDBC it was working fine.

Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts from `util.Utility` where you connect to the database?

Comment: -807 does not look like a valid DB2 error code; are you sure about it? What DB2 version/platform are you accessing?

Comment: It is, [at least on z/OS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fn807.htm).

Comment: There's the answer then: _ACCESS DENIED: PACKAGE package-name IS NOT ENABLED FOR ACCESS FROM connection-type connection-name_

Comment: It doesn't seems like a package access issue as the same is working using JDBC

Comment: @mthmulders Exception is thrown when a select query is fired from Utility class. JNDI lookup is able to return a valid connection object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this error quite somtimes. It almoust happens after installing a fixpack on the database.

I solved this always after rebinding client packages.

Look [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0011077.html) (DB2 v9.5 infocenter) for how to do this.

--- UPDATE ---

Check also your DB2 JDBC driver version.

Comment: I figured out the problem. There were 2 issues: (a) The warning messsages (b) Exception while firing queries. For (a) I updated the DB2JCC drivers and it solved the problem. for second (b) as the package picked because of default isolation of Websphere was SYSLN300, it had some binding issues. To avoid this package getting picked, I changed the Isolation level to READ_COMMITTED which changed the package from SYSLN300 to SYSLN200 which was properly binded. Thus, the queries ran fine. @Seb.B. you were right !